# Successive differentiation of nth order

Tags: derivatives

Any clue to solve the below please

> If $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\sin^{-1}x$ prove that $$\left(1-x^2\right)y_{n+1}-\left( 2n-1\right) xy_n - n\left( n-2\right) y_{n-1} = 0$$

Comment: Prove for $n=1,2$ then use induction.

Comment: How to find nth derivative of the above "y" pls

Comment: you don't have to compute it explicitly. You only have to verify your induction hypothesis.

Comment: Please include the formula using MathJax rather than a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prove the relation for n=1 
You only need to calculate the first two derivatives of that function..

$$\left(1-x^2\right)y''-xy' +y=0$$

Then use induction to prove that:

$$\left( 1-x^2\right) y_{n+2} -(2n+1)xy_{n+1} -\left( n^2-1\right)y_{n}=0$$

Starting with the induction hypothesis:

\begin{align}\left(1-x^2\right) y_{n+1} -(2n-1)xy_n -n(n-2)y_{n-1}=0 \\
-2xy_{n+1}+\left(1-x^2\right) y_{n+2}-(2n-1)y_n -(2n-1)xy_{n+1} -n(n-2)y_{n}=0\\
\left(1-x^2\right) y_{n+2}-(2n-1)xy_{n+1} -2xy_{n+1} -n(n-2)y_{n}-(2n-1)y_n =0 \\
\left(1-x^2\right) y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1} -n(n-2)y_{n}-(2n-1)y_n =0
\end{align}
Finally

$$\left(1-x^2\right) y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1} -\left( n^2-1\right)y_n =0$$

Comment: (1−x²)y′′−xy′+y=0 is this true for the above function? when we find y'' & y' and plugin in this equation, it seems not satisfied. Please help me to bring (1−x²)y′′−xy′+y=0 from y by differentiation

Comment: You should post what you did... The proof by induction need to be true for a certain n. The equation I wrote is for $n=1$. You can also try to prove that it's true for $n=2$

Comment: In MathJax, don't use `x²` $x²$, use `x^2` $x^2$, which is easier to read.

Comment: And if you hate induction then, substitute x as sin x and then use Leibnitz's theorem.